# Parsing human readable relative times

Tags: python, time

I would like to parse human terms like `3 days ago` in `python 2.7` to get a timedelta equivalent.

For example:

```
>>> relativetimeparer.parser('3 days ago')
datetime.timedelta(3)
```

I have tried the `dateparser` module.

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('3 days ago')
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 20, 2, 57, 23, 372538)
>>> datetime.now() - dateparser.parse('3 days ago')
datetime.timedelta(3, 35999, 999232)
```

It parses relative time directly to `datetime` without the option of returning a `timedelta`. It also seems to think that 3 days ago is actually 3 days and 10 hours ago. So it seems to be invoking my timezone offset from Greenwich too (+10 hours).

Is there a better module for parsing human readable relative times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could specify the `RELATIVE_BASE` setting:

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> res = dateparser.parse('3 days ago', settings={'RELATIVE_BASE': now})
>>> now - res
datetime.timedelta(3)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had looked on the readthedocs page, but that particular feature was not clearly documented.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to tip about the interesting [Arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library that has a builtin `dehumanize()` method.  The `dehumanize()` method takes a human readable string and use it to shift a moment into a past time or into the future.  The above could then be accomplished as simply as:

```python
>>> import arrow
>>> now = arrow.now()
<Arrow [2021-10-15T14:43:20.506200+02:00]>
>>> now.dehumanize('3 days ago')
<Arrow [2021-10-12T14:43:20.506200+02:00]>
>>> now.dehumanize('3 days ago') - now
datetime.timedelta(days=-3)
```